# pip install -e . behind proxy

Tags: python, pip, proxy, setuptools

I'm developing a Python-application on my private computer (Win11) supposed to be run on my work-computer (Win10) behind proxy. The application is working fine on my private computer, but I get stuck on "No matching distribution found for setuptools" for my work-computer. I am quite new in Python-world so I hope someone can help me find where I stumble and how to proceed. Apologies for incorrect terminology due to limited knowledge about this.

I am using Anaconda and virtual environment for both computers. My folder structure is according to [this](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/explanation/goodpractices.html)

```
myapp/
    pyproject.toml
    requirements.txt
    setup.cfg
    setup.py
    src/
        myapp/
            __init__.py
            app.py
            scripts.py
    tests/
```

setup.py contain:

```
from setuptools import setup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup()
```

setup.cfg contain (in addition to [metadata])

```
[options]
zip_safe = False
include_package_data = True
package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:
install_requires = 
    matplotlib
    numpy
    pandas
    PyQt5
    scikit_image
    scipy

[options.package_data]
* = *.txt, *.md

[options.packages.find]
where=src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    myapp = myapp.myapp:main
```

On my private computer I can, after activating a virtual environment, do:

`pip install -e .`

and then run my program by

`python -m myapp.myapp`

On my work-computer I succeed installing single packages using

`pip install --proxy=http://<myproxy> pandas`

When I try
`pip install --proxy=http://<myproxy> -e .`

it fails by

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools (from version: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools
```

I've also tried with `python -m` before pip. Same error.

The installed setuptools had a higher version number than on my private computer so I installed the same version in the virtual environment on my work-computer. Same error again.

I've tried to take away all the external requirements from setup.cfg and then `pip install -e .`. Same error.

I've also tested setting up the virtual environment and using `pip install -e .` on another private computer running Windows 10. It works as it should.

Why do I get the error on setuptools on my work-computer when setuptools is installed and in a version that do work on my private computer? It seems that it fails running setup.py because of this. Any ideas or knowledge on how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by creating a file pip.ini in the pip folder (AppData/local/pip) with this content:
*[global]
proxy = http://user:password@proxyserver:port*

I also added two new environment variables : http_proxy and https_proxy. Each of them with the value *http://user:password@proxyserver:port*
Hopes it helps

Comment: I guess I ended up doing something similar. I learned that I could change the conda settings so I have added the proxy to the .conda file.